# How to apply Bonferroni correction to confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, bonferroni

I want to apply the Bonferroni correction to the following confidence interval:
[image]

Since $\alpha _{Bonf}\:=\:\frac{0.05}{k}$ and I have two groups, should I just substitute $\alpha$ above with $\frac{0.05}{2}$?

Comment: Stéphane Laurent's [answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/449626) might help.